# Docker - exposing IP addresses to DNS server

Tags: docker, dns, apache-zookeeper

Looking at the `iptables` of my docker host i get something like this:

`sudo iptables -L`

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:http-alt
```

I was able to assign a durable IP address like this:

```
sudo ip addr add 10.0.0.99/8 dev eth0
docker run -d -p 10.0.0.99:8888:8080 tomcat:8
```

but that address is only available on this machine, as in I need to ssh into it and ping it from this box.

Reading through this, it looks like i need to add a custom bridge:

[Custom Docker Bridge](http://jpetazzo.github.io/2013/10/16/configure-docker-bridge-network/)

Is there a way to make the bridge hand fresh ips from the DHCP server? For example if my DHCP server assigned addresses from 10.1.1.x - I want to assign those addresses to Docker containers.

Would this involve a generic *nix way of pushing my iptable /etc/hosts ip addresses and dns names to a DNS server so other machines outside of the Docker cluster can ping those machines?

I have port forwarding working but need to do the same with the ip addresses as Zookeeper only tracks the internal Docker ip addresses and hostnames as I've defined them in my docker-compose.yml.

Comment: Looking at consul -  it looks like I can spin up a docker DNS http://artplustech.com/docker-consul-dns-registrator/ But I'm still not sure how I can make that resolve docker host names.  Could I add the consul port and docker iP to a list of dns servers?